# How to dectect collision between 2 triangle in a 3d space?

Tags: java, 3d, collision-detection

I want to make a triangle collision detector (or in general, plane/area collision) in 3d space (with java (without java3D)). I'm blocked at the collision part, the place where computer detect that the area of 2 triangles intersect. I want to trigger some kind of event when 2 shapes collide and stop collide and I actually don't know where to start. I consider to do SAT in 3d, but it seem expensive to applied in a 3d context. Is there a better way to detect 3d collision of shapes in 3d space?

SAT explanation : http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/

**EDIT** In concrete context, this will be usefull to detect prism's face collision

Comment: How do you deal with a 2d shape (triangle) in a 3d environment?

Comment: 3 coordinates in 3d environement, so the triangle can be place (I could said a cube instead of a triangle, but a triangle can be at the base of every shape in 3d (1 triangle = 1 face)), also a 2d can be represent as a plane on a 3d grid

Comment: You still have time to edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient way to detect triangle-triangle intersections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585459/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-triangle-triangle-intersections)

Comment: Unfortunatly akuzminykh, this is on a 3d Eucledean space and your topic is on 2d Eucledean space. Still thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection of rays, planes and triangles:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html

Triangle-Triangle Intersection Determination:
http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/poli/n48/n48a3.pdf

A Triangle-Triangle Intersection Algorithm:
http://web.mst.edu/~chaman/home/pubs/2015WimoTriangleTrianglePublished.pdf

Comment: This seem powerfull and very well explained, thank you very much