# Detecting 3D Collisions

Tags: math, collision-detection, game-development, lwjgl, triangle

I am currently working on a lwjgl project where I need to detect collisions between 3D triangles. I'm using OpenGL, and I'm seeking guidance on the most efficient and accurate way to achieve this.

To give you some context, I have a set of triangles defined by their vertices in 3D space, and I need to check for collisions between them.

I'm wondering if there are simpe and optimized algorithms that I can leverage to make this collision detection process. Additionally, if anyone has experience or knowledge regarding this specific problem, I'd greatly appreciate any insights or resources you can provide.

I have done some research on this topic for example this algorithm: [https://cis.temple.edu/~lakaemper/courses/cis350_2004/etc/moeller_triangle.pdf](https://cis.temple.edu/%7Elakaemper/courses/cis350_2004/etc/moeller_triangle.pdf), but still looking for a simpler, more practical and efficient solution. Any recommendations or code samples would be very helpful.

**I already found the solution and described it below**

Comment: "I'm still looking for a more simple, practical and efficient solution" more than what, though? I don't see a description of what you already found and tried in your post. As asking for books, resources, etc. is [off topic on Stackoverflow](/help/on-topic), you should probably talk a bit about [what you already tried](/help/how-to-ask), ideally with code that shows off what you have now that isn't working the way you want it to, and a discussion of what you already did/searched for/etc. to try to improve that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61310663/3871028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's line - plane intersection test in 3D space

We have points:
A(Ax, Ay, Az),
B(Bx, By, Bz),
C(Cx, Cy, Cz),
P(Px, Py, Pz),
Q(Qx, Qy, Qz).

That's an equation of a plane defined by 3 points A, B, C on it. ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

```
|x-A.x      y-A.y       z-A.z  |
|B.x-A.x    B.y-A.y     B.z-A.z| = 0 
|C.x-A.x    C.y-A.y     C.z-A.z|
```

And that paramedic equation of a line(i hope thats the right name (: )

```
t = (x-P.x)/(Q.x-P.x) = (y-P.y)/(Q.y-P.y) = (z-P.z)/(Q.z-P.z)
```

Combine these together to get intersection point:

```
|t(Q.y-P.x)+P.x-A.x   t(Q.y-P.y)+P.y-A.y    t(Q.z-P.z)+P.z-A.z  |
|B.x-A.x              B.y-A.y               B.z-A.z             | = 0
|C.x-A.x              C.y-A.y               C.z-A.z             |
```

```
    a = -(Px-Ax)*(By-Ay)*(Cz-Az) -
         (Py-Ay)*(Bz-Az)*(Cx-Ax) -
         (Pz-Az)*(Bx-Ax)*(Cy-Ay) +
         (Pz-Az)*(By-Ay)*(Cx-Ax) +
         (Px-Ax)*(Bz-Az)*(Cy-Ay) +
         (Py-Ay)*(Bx-Ax)*(Cz-Az);

    b = (Qx-Px)*(By-Ay)*(Cz-Az) +
        (Qy-Py)*(Bz-Az)*(Cx-Ax) +
        (Qz-Pz)*(Bx-Ax)*(Cy-Ay) -
        (Qz-Pz)*(By-Ay)*(Cx-Ax) -
        (Qx-Px)*(Bz-Az)*(Cy-Ay) -
        (Qy-Py)*(Bx-Ax)*(Cz-Az);
```

```
    a = b = 0 => ABC and PQ are in the same plane => infinite amount of intersection points
    b = 0 => A plane and a line do not intersect => no intersection
```

Now, find the point of intersection:

```
    t = a/b
    
    x = t(Q.x-P.x)+P.x
    y = t(Q.y-P.y)+P.y
    z = t(Q.z-P.z)+P.z
```

So if that point belongs to triangle ABC and line **segment** AB there is an intersection.

So you can repeat that process with every edge og the 2nd triangle to find the intersection between triangles.