# How to test if two triangles are colliding in 3D space?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, collision-detection, sat

I'm using C++ and OpenGL.  Whats the fastest and best way to implement triangle to triangle collision in 3D given 3 vertices of each triangle?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585459/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-triangle-triangle-intersections

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs277/resources/papers/Moller1997b.pdf